# In the ACQUIRE statement in Cobol what does the Program Device Name refer to?

Tags: ibm-midrange, cobol

Here is the IBM documentation but it doesn't tell you where program-device-name is defined

ACQUIRE program-device-name FOR SUB-FILE.

Comment: Is this [documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r1/ic2924/books/c0925392320.htm) helpful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read about [ACQUIRE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzasb%2Fsc092539541.htm) in the COBOL reference, you will also see that it can be used for display devices.  As I recall, the display device must be connected, but not logged in at the time.

The reference says about the device-identifier:

> The identifier must refer to an alphanumeric data item 10 characters or less in length.

It doesn't seem to care whether it is defined in working-storage or elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

The ACQUIRE statement is an IBM iSeries extention to COBOL to support ICF programming (Intersystem Communication Function). For an overview
see: [ICF Programming](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/books/c4154420.pdf). Chapter 4 describes
Devices, what they are and how they are defined.

There is no short answer to this question. You will have to do some reading and the above reference should be a good starting point.